# Avoid unchecked cast

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting

I cannot find a way to avoid an unchecked cast in the following case

```
class EventBus {
    val eventToHandle: MutableMap<KClass<out Event>, Event.() -> Unit> = mutableMapOf()

    final inline fun <reified T : Event> register(noinline handler: T.() -> Unit) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        eventToHandle[T::class] = handler as Event.() -> Unit
    }

    fun fire(event: Event) {
        eventToHandle[event::class]?.invoke(event)
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing handler for class ${event::class}")
    }
}
```

My goal is to enforce the map to contains only lambda that has `Event` (or one of subtypes of it) as receiver but at the same time I want a reference to the **actual** implementation of `Event` while registering lambda.
In this way I can use members of his implementation without casting every time.

An example (`requestId` is a field of `RequestExpiredEvent`):

```
eventBus.register<RequestExpiredEvent> {
            requestService.setExpiredByRequestId(requestId)
        }
```

I know that "consumer lambda" has no covariance and that they are contravariant, but I guess if there is a way.
An ugly workaround that I found was:

```
    final inline fun <reified T : Event> register(crossinline block: T.() -> Unit) {
        val handler: Event.() -> Unit = { this as T; block(this) }
        eventToHandle[T::class] = handler
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you can simplify the second version `eventToHandle[T::class] = { block(this as T) }` but this can still lead to a `ClassCastException`, and actually it doesn't differ from the previous one

Answer (score 0):

This is a dangerous cast to make. `SomeEventSubtype.() -> Unit` is not a subtype of `Event.() -> Unit`. It's the other way around.

Suppose Event is an open class and you have this subclass:

```
class SubEvent: Event() {
    fun hello(): Unit {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

Now you try casting it:

```
val hello: SubEvent.() -> Unit = SubEvent::hello
val helloCasted = hello as Event.() -> Unit
```

When you try to call `helloCasted.invoke(Event())`, it will throw a ClassCastException when it tries to cast your Event to a SubEvent. You can't call `hello` with any instance of `Event` as an input, because only `SubEvent` has a `hello` function to call.

The compiler will catch this error if you try to implicitly cast it:

```
val hello: SubEvent.() -> Unit = SubEvent::hello
val helloCasted: Event.() -> Unit = hello // compiler error
```

It does work the other way around. When looking at the *inputs* of functions, you can think of the type hierarchy as inverted.

```
val toStringFun: Event.() -> Unit = Event::toString
val toStringCasted: SubEvent.() -> Unit = toStringFun // OK
```

There isn't a way to solve this without doing an unchecked cast somewhere, because you are storing different types of objects in your map. But you need to move your casting to the `fire` function so it will know what to cast it to. You can store the functions as type `Any` in the map since you will be casting them anyway. Something like this:

```
class EventBus {
    val eventToHandle: MutableMap<KClass<out Event>, Any> = mutableMapOf()

    inline fun <reified T : Event> register(noinline handler: T.() -> Unit) {
        eventToHandle[T::class] = handler
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    inline fun <reified T : Event> fire(event: T) {
        (eventToHandle[T::class] as? T.() -> Unit)?.invoke(event)
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing handler for class ${event::class}")
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your solution. It's a better design to put the ```@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")```in the fire method.
By the way, I perfectly know what do you mean regarding the covariance and contravariance of lambda, but I cannot find a way where my previous code can thow a ```ClassCastExcepion```. It's impossible to register a lambda that is not coupled with the correct ```KClass```. Am I missing something? Thanks btw!

Comment: Oh, maybe it’s fine the way you’re doing it. I wrote the first part before looking at how you actually retrieve and call these functions. Due to type erasure, I suppose it won’t ever have to cast the events because you keep them matched up correctly to their function types. But I don’t think it makes sense to make the map’s key type one that you know for a fact is incorrect for the actual objects you’re putting in. It should either be type `Nothing.() -> Unit` or more simply just `Any` since you are casting it anyway every time you retrieve them.

Comment: True as well. Can I ask you why should it make sense to declare the function as ```Nothing.() -> Unit```? I understand that every ```T.() -> Unit``` would be a subtype, so no cast should be needed, but **logically** I found it misleading. I can't even understand what it should be a legit function of type ```Nothing.() -> Unit``` :D

Comment: "But I don’t think it makes sense to make the map’s key type one that you know for a fact is incorrect for the actual objects you’re putting in"  


The idea was to make explicit that the key of the map it's not an `Any` object but a function of events

Comment: Since `Nothing` is a subtype of everything, `Nothing.() -> Unit` is a supertype of all functions with a single input and returns `Unit`. So this gets you a bit closer to expressing what goes in the map. Unfortunately there's no way to set an upper bound on the input type of a function type declaration, so you can't bound it between `Event` and `Nothing`.